# No consigo entrenar mi red neuronal con los datos que le paso

Tags: python, redes-neuronales, google-colab

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de prueba en Google Colab con la librería tensorflow, aún no tengo mucha idea de las redes neuronales, he visto este vídeo [Tu primera red neuronal en Python y Tensorflow](https://youtu.be/iX_on3VxZzk) y estoy trasteando con su código.

El código consiste en simular el juego de Wordle, en el que hay que adivinar la palabra del día, según que letras pongas, el sistema te mostrará si no existe (en nuestro caso será
"**n**"), existe pero no está en la posición ("**m**") o existe ("**b**").

He hecho un par de ejemplos para entrenar al modelo en el que la matriz de caracteres llamada `palabras` guarda las palabras que se van introduciendo:

```
palabras = np.array([[['P', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'L'], ['M', 'A', 'R', 'T', 'A'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'I', 'S'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'V', 'E'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'V', 'O']], [['C', 'A', 'Z', 'A', 'R'], ['C', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'R'], ['C', 'O', 'S', 'E', 'R'], ['C', 'O', 'M', 'E', 'R']]])
```

En este caso primero se introduce la palabra "PANAL", después "MARTA", así hasta la palabra correcta: "SALVO", ese es el primer ejemplo o partida, la siguiente partida comenzaría con la palabra "CAZAR" y terminaría con la palabra adivinada correctamente: "COMER".

Vamos a ver ahora las pistas que da el sistema para ver que letras son las correctas y cuales no.

```
pistas = np.array([[['n', 'b', 'n', 'n', 'm'], ['n', 'b', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'n', 'n'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'n'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']], [['b', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'b'], ['b', 'n', 'n', 'b', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'n', 'b', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']]])
```

En esta matriz almacenamos pistas: n (no existe la letra), m (existe pero esta mal colocada) y b (existe y esta bien colocada), cada pista se coloca en la misma posición a la que hace referencia en la matriz palabras, por ejemplo la palabra PANAL tiene la letra "P", "N" y la segunda "A" mal y que no existen, la primera letra "A" está bien y en la posición correcta, la letra "L" existe pero no está en la posición correcta. Así sucesivamente con el resto de palabras hasta que todas las letras están bien.

El error surge en la línea de después de declarar la matriz palabras, esta línea: `mi_palabras = np.array(palabras, dtype=str)`

El error es el siguiente:

```
<ipython-input-11-68fd6a861509>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  palabras = np.array([[['P', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'L'], ['M', 'A', 'R', 'T', 'A'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'I', 'S'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'V', 'E'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'V', 'O']], [['C', 'A', 'Z', 'A', 'R'], ['C', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'R'], ['C', 'O', 'S', 'E', 'R'], ['C', 'O', 'M', 'E', 'R']]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-68fd6a861509> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 palabras = np.array([[['P', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'L'], ['M', 'A', 'R', 'T', 'A'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'I', 'S'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'V', 'E'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'V', 'O']], [['C', 'A', 'Z', 'A', 'R'], ['C', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'R'], ['C', 'O', 'S', 'E', 'R'], ['C', 'O', 'M'...
----> 2 mi_palabras = np.array(palabras, dtype=str)
      3 print(mi_palabras)
      4 
      5 pistas = np.array([[['n', 'b', 'n', 'n', 'm'], ['n', 'b', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'n', 'n'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'n'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']], [['b', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'b'], ['b', 'n', 'n', 'b', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'n', 'b', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'b'0...

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

oculta1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, input_shape=[1])
oculta2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3)
salida = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
modelo = tf.keras.Sequential([oculta1, oculta2, salida])

modelo.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1),
    loss='mean_squared_error'
)

palabras = np.array([[['P', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'L'], ['M', 'A', 'R', 'T', 'A'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'I', 'S'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'V', 'E'], ['S', 'A', 'L', 'V', 'O']], [['C', 'A', 'Z', 'A', 'R'], ['C', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'R'], ['C', 'O', 'S', 'E', 'R'], ['C', 'O', 'M', 'E', 'R']]])
mi_palabras = np.array(palabras, dtype=str)
print(mi_palabras)

pistas = np.array([[['n', 'b', 'n', 'n', 'm'], ['n', 'b', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'n', 'n'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'n'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']], [['b', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'b'], ['b', 'n', 'n', 'b', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'n', 'b', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']]])
mi_pistas = np.array(pistas, dtype=str)


mi_palabras = np.array(mi_palabras.tolist())
mi_palabras = np.expand_dims(mi_palabras, axis=-1)
mi_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(mi_palabras)


mi_pistas = np.array(mi_pistas.tolist())
mi_pistas = np.expand_dims(mi_pistas, axis=-1)
mi_tensorSol = tf.convert_to_tensor(mi_pistas)


print("Comenzando entrenamiento...")
historial = modelo.fit(mi_palabras, mi_pistas,epochs=1000, verbose=False)
print("Modelo entrenado!")
```

Recomiendo mucho ver el vídeo que especifiqué antes, está muy bien explicado.

Gracias.